# Run imported rake task with bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to import and run a *rake* task, that I put in the *Gemfile*

I ran the `bundle install` and it find the installed *gem* containing my rake task there. But, when I run the `bundle exec rake <namespace>:<task>`, then then I get this output instead of success:

```
Don't know how to build task 'forum2discourse:import_punbb'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0-turbo/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0-turbo/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It looks like the *task* weren't found. How should I instruct the `bundle install` so it finds the *task*?

Comment: `bundle exec rake -T` show your tasks?

Comment: you have put your taks in **Gemfile**?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I only put `gem 'forum2discourse'` to the `Gemfile`

Comment: @Зелёный no, the `bundle exec rake -T` is not showing it

Comment: http://andyatkinson.com/blog/2014/06/23/sharing-rake-tasks-in-gems

Comment: @Daiku I don't want to create new rake task, I want to just an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the *Gem* I was trying to install isn't published yet, so adding

```
gem 'forum2discourse'
```

to the `Gemfile` isn't enough. I wast trying to fix this by checking out the repo, then installing the `Gem` globally? with `sudo bundle install <gem>`. The `bundle install` then stopped complaining about not having the needed gem, but it wouldn't expose the tasks in the gem. However, having the link to the github repo in the gem definition fixes the issue:

```
gem 'forum2discourse', github: 'initforthe/forum2discourse'
```

Ruby is magick :-)

Answer (score 0):

According the [rake task import manual](http://andyatkinson.com/blog/2014/06/23/sharing-rake-tasks-in-gems) (provided by @Daiku). In the **Rakefile**, you can enumerate all the gems required in you project, and then try import all the rake task exported in those gems, if any, like this:

```
Gem::Specification.all.each do |spec|
   Dir.glob('**/*.rake').each {|file| load file }
end
```

The try:

```
$ rake -T
```

Comment: it prints: `NOTE: Specification.all called from /vagrant/Rakefile:9:in '<top (required)>'` and then the *rake* task is not in the list of available tasks.